# CloseHandler is not called for a gorilla/websocket if I am not reading messages anywhere, I simply get a write error eventually

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I have a websocket server using gorilla/websocket.

I have a situation where I am simply writing messages to a set of websockets. My custom CloseHandler is never called when I close the websocket on the browser side.

However, adding a goroutine that calls ReadMessage indefinitely (till some error) leads to the CloseHandler being invoked.

Here's the basic idea: 
In one goroutine, I run something like this:

```
for {
    for client := range clients {
        client.stream <- data
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

and the other code, called in a separate goroutine, one per client:

```
go (func() {
    // If I call wsock.ReadMessage here, my CloseHandler works!
})()

for msg := range myclient.stream {
    if err := wsock.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg); err != nil {
        break
    }
}
```

When I close the websocket on the browser side, I expect the CloseHandler to be called, however, it's never called, instead, I eventually get an error on the WriteMessage call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The close handler is called when a [close message is received from the peer](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.SetCloseHandler). The application [must read the connection to receive close and other control messages](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#hdr-Control_Messages).

If the application does not read the connection or the peer does not send a close message, then the close handler will not be called.

If your goal is to detect closed connections, then read the connection until an error as returned as shown in [the documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#hdr-Control_Messages):

```
func readLoop(c *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        if _, _, err := c.NextReader(); err != nil {
            c.Close()
            break
        }
    }
 }
```

The application should only set a close handler when the application must perform some action before the connection bounces the close message back to the peer.